# How to remove specific querystring on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, indexof

Let's say I have the following url string:

```
www.mysite.com?this&that&theOtherThing
```

I know how to add query strings to any link, but am unaware of how to remove one.

For instance, I know I can add a query string by doing the following:

```
//just add within the href
<a href="?this">submit</a>

or

//set the href within jquery
$('button').attr('href', currentUrl + '&that');
```

How would I remove that same query on click?

I tried the following, but got an NaN error:

```
$('button').attr('href', currentUrl - '&that');
```

Does anyone have advice on how to remove a query?

Comment: Replace `&that` with `''`

Comment: currentUrl is a string. Use string manipulation to change it to what you want it to be. string + anotherstring adds to a string, and string.replace() can replace a part of a string with another string (possibly even empty string.)

Comment: You could use replace in this case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: -Ohgodwhy but if I do that and use only currentUrl my attribute of href '&that' is still part of my current url, right? I'm trying to make sure it's remove from the string on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to replace "?that", not "&that".  Second, you have an a tag that doesn't have an id, but you're setting the 'href' attribute of an element with the id of 'button', which doesn't appear in your code snippet.

You got a NaN error because you're trying to subtract "?that" from a string.  Instead, use string.replace("?that", "") - which will remove the "%that", but not anything after it (if there is something).  If there is something after "&that" in your string, get the indexOf("?that") and then set the string to a substring of itself like so:

html:

```
<a href="www.blah.com/page.aspx?that=hello" id="linkToModify">Click me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var urlString = $("#linktoModify").prop("href");
urlString = urlString.toString().substring(0, urlString.indexOf("?"));
$("#linkToModify").prop("href", urlString);
```

Also, keep in mind that your question is a bit misleading.  You're trying to edit a string with javascript, not remove a query string.  Query strings are readonly and cannot be removed, but you can easily modify a string, which appears to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: ...and apologizes for my misleading comment. I'm a web designer who has self taught myself jquery. Sometimes my annunciation of the proper terms is off :)

Comment: No problem - now you know the difference!

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_args(a, url, arg){
  a.attr('href', url.replace(arg,''));
}
```

html

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove_args(this, 'www.mysite.com?this&that&theOtherThing', '&that')">URL</a>
```

try something like this. just a small scenario